# After Windows 2016 is Expired, what is the way forward for Office online server in Sharepoint 2019?

Tags: 2019, office-online-server, windows-server-2016

We are recommending our client to use **Office Online Server(OOS)** for their new project (in Sharepoint2019) on document view capabilities. We found in the Web/MSDN Blogs are saying that OOS is **supported only in Windows Server 2016**.But, They want to upgrade all their Servers to Windows Server 2019.Here are the following questions that we have.

1.**After Windows 2016 is Expired**, what is the way forward for Office online server.?

2.Do we have any thing else to achieve this functionality **apart from Office Online Server** as this has limited support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, Microsoft want to focus their support on their cloud solution. Therefore on-premise product like OOS will get lesser support.

However, OOS is a standalone product which do not involve a lot of integration. You can install it on Windows Server 2019. I did it myself and do not encounter any problem so far. Here is [an article](https://createsitecollection.medium.com/install-prerequisite-of-office-online-server-oos-on-windows-server-2019-8673c54d064f) talk about the installation.

I am not Microsoft staff. I have asked MS similar question before and not getting any answer.

Here is my comment on your questions:

1. After Windows 2016 is Expired, MS is not going to support OOS on-premise. The last OOS patch [was released on 2018](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server-release-schedule). Customers should subscribe to their cloud platform.
2. There are many open source or business project out in the market. For best compatibility for MS Office 365's file, no doubt you have to subscribe **Office 365**. Other alternatives are Google Docs, Onlyoffice, ZOHO, CryptPad, etc.

Comment: We will also try installing OOS in windows server 2019 once we get servers and update here. Thanks for sharing.